# laravel search with multiple words in arabic return only first array and others is empty

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add a search bar in my site
this is my controller

```
public function search(string $search){
        $products = products::with('descriptions');
        $searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $search, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $results=array();
        $allValues=[];

        foreach ($searchValues as $value){
            $q= $products->where(function ($quary) use ($value){
                $quary->where('title','LIKE','%'.$value.'%')
                ->orWhereHas('descriptions',function($quary) use ($value){
                    $quary->where('description', 'LIKE','%' . $value . '%');
                });

            })->get()->toArray();
        array_push($results,$q);

        }
        $finalResult = array();

        foreach($results as $key => $value)
        {
             $finalResult[$key] =$value;
        }



        return $finalResult;
    }
```

This code is working  well when i put 2 English words but if I put Arabic words in the search bar i got only result for the first word and the rest of word send empty arrays like in this screenshot:

[image]

I don't  know what is the difference between Arabic and English words so anyone have a hint ?